# Regular Expressions: pull the data between "FOO" and "BAR"

Tags: python, regex

I have this string right here:

```
*TACK F\u00d6R DIN BOKNING MED RYANAIR*****\r\n------------------------------\r\n\r\nV\u00e4nligen svara inte p\u00e5 detta e-postmeddelande.****\r\n------------------------------\r\n\r\nDITT BOKNINGSNUMMER \u00c4R:* A1A1A1*****\r\n\r\nF\u00d6R ATT F\u00c5 RESA M\u00c5STE DU CHECKA IN VIA INTERNET OCH P\u00c5 FLYGPLATSEN VISA UPP\r\nDITT INTERNETBOARDINGKORT OCH GILTIG ACCEPTERAD RESEHANDLING. PASSAGERARE\r\nSOM INTE VISAR UPP ETT BOARDINGKORT P\u00c5 FLYGPLATSEN KOMMER ATT BLI\r\nDEBITERADE EN STRAFFAVGIFT F\u00d6R NY-UTSKRIFT P\u00c5 EURO40/GBP40.(varje\r\nboardingkort m\u00e5ste vara utskrivet och presenteras p\u00e5 individuella A4-ark).**\r\n**\r\n\r\nDu kan checka in via Internet fr\u00e5n 15 dagar fram till 4 timmar innan\r\nflygets schemalagda avg\u00e5ng.****\r\n\r\nRESEPLAN/KVITTO \u2013 alla tider \u00e4r lokala.****\r\n\r\nUTRESA****\r\n\r\nFr\u00e5n Milano (Bergamo) (BGY) till Stockholm Skavsta (NYO)\r\nSat, 14Aug10 Flyg FR1944 Avg\u00e5ng BGY kl 21:00 och ankomst NYO kl 23:30****\r\n\r\nPASSAGERARE****\r\n\r\n
```

And, I need to pull the data between "UTRESA" and "PASSAGERARE". So I tried this:

```
re.search(r'UTRESA (.+)PASSAGERARE',x)
```

And for some reason its not pulling the data! Could you guys explain to my why I'm not pulling the data, and a solution for it?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the [`DOTALL` flag](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) when matching newlines:

```
re.search(r'UTRESA(.+)PASSAGERARE', x, re.DOTALL)
```

and there's no space after UTRESA.

Demo:

```
>>> re.search(r'UTRESA(.+)PASSAGERARE', x, re.DOTALL).groups()
('****\r\n\r\nFr\\u00e5n Milano (Bergamo) (BGY) till Stockholm Skavsta (NYO)\r\nSat, 14Aug10 Flyg FR1944 Avg\\u00e5ng BGY kl 21:00 och ankomst NYO kl 23:30****\r\n\r\n',)
```

Comment: I think you mean `re.search(r'UTRESA(.+)PASSAGERARE',x, re.DOTALL)`.  AFAIK `re.MULTILINE` only affects `^` and `$`.  [Also, the space needs to go.]

Comment: @DSM: Oops, shooting from the hip there.. Thanks.